# Using MAKEFILE for an existing Django project

Tags: django, makefile

I have an existing project with Django, and I have been using `paver` to run/test and install requirements for it. I am thinking to switch to `MAKEFILE` as most of the other projects are now using a makefile.

1. How to install `make` in the console? maybe using `pip`?
2. What are the prereqs for start using makefile.

Any other help or tutorials that may help.

### **Example:**

https://github.com/edx/course-discovery/blob/master/Makefile

Comment: Why Downvote? can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Prereqs in using `make` for your existing project.
1. Create a make file with the name `MAKEFILE`.
2. Add your commands.

## EG.

```
requirements: ## install basic environment requirements
    pip install -qr requirements/requirements.txt --exists-action w
```